# Use of "that was" in the active voice

Tags: grammar, sentence, passive-voice, active-voice

Hi smart English people!
I'm writing a sentence in the active past tense describing a notebook. The wording is awkward.
"I treasured my mint green, pocket-sized notebook designed with silhouettes of songbirds perched on daisies."

"I treasured... notebook" is a complete thought, but the rest of the sentence seems to long and wordy of a clause. Would the sentence make more sense if I changed to "I treasured my mint green, pocket-sized notebook *that was* designed with silhouettes of songbirds perched on daisies."?

I want to keep writing in the active voice, so this isn't the perfect solution. Any suggestions? Is my original sentence correct?

Comment: The main problem is not one of tense.  'designed' is not quite right:  'decorated' is what you need here.  But actually, a you need is '...notebook with its silhouettes of ...'  The word 'pocket-sized ' is unnecessary. If it's a notebook it's probably smallish.

Comment: Thank you Tuffy!

Comment: @Tuffy I agree with you about "decorated with" rather than "designed with" but disagree that "pocket-sized" is unnecessary. Most dealers in stationery in the UK like [this one](https://www.theworks.co.uk/c/stationery/notepads?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIz7LhwpyD7AIVzuntCh0TtgmkEAQYDCABEgIwMPD_BwE) sell A4 notebooks and you need a pretty big pocket for one of those.

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, Rachael, I was thinking about that fact, and you are right.  My point, perhaps should have been pocket-sized' is more the kind of description you might give to the assistant in a railway lost property office, and so detracts from the literary description of its appearance.  The colour and design make it pretty, while the size makes it convenient.  'little' would be a more 'aesthetic' word.  "I treasured my mint green little notebook, decorated with ...".  But I have, I'm afraid, gone off topic by departing from strict language usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with all the comments but would insist that your original sentence is just fine the way it is. You can add more detail to make it a more formal description but it adds nothing and takes away a little bit here and there until it has no charm to offer. Leave it be.

Comment: @ Elliot, Agree with you.